# Adding a VLAN (over bond/lacp) interface to bridge makes physical interfaces to go down

Tags: centos, linux-networking, vlan, bridge, bonding

I have a working configuration of a team interface bonding two physical interfaces, with several VLANs.

```
ens1f1 -----               |--- team0.1826 (172.18.x.y/28)
           |--- team0 -----|--- team0.1651
ens2f0 -----               |--- team9.1655
```

I need to start a kvm virtual machine on this host, on the vlan 1826 network. So I am trying to add a bridge including the `team0.1826` interface in the following manner:

- remove the previous vlan interface

```
nmcli con del team0.1826
```

- Add a bridge interface

```
nmcli connection add type bridge con-name br0 ifname br0 \
        ipv4.method manual ipv4.addresses '172.18.x.y/28' ipv4.gateway '172.18.x.z'
```

- Recreate the vlan interface, as a slave to the bridge

```
nmcli connection add type vlan con-name team01826 ifname team0.1826 \
        dev team0 id 1826 master br0 slave-type bridge
```

It happens that as soon as I run this last command, all the interfaces are going down, including the physical ones. I am guessing that doing this somehow breaks the LACP communication to the switch, making the interfaces to be brought down. However I am not understanding what I am doing wrong and how to make things work. As soon as I remove the new bridge-slave `team0.1826` interface, interfaces are going UP again.

Some additional information:

- team0 configuration

```
$ cat ifcfg-team0
PROXY_METHOD=none
BROWSER_ONLY=no
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=no
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE=stable-privacy
NAME=team0
UUID=24c8380b-43ca-4977-9dc0-27e27e3ec387
DEVICE=team0
ONBOOT=yes
DEVICETYPE=Team
TEAM_CONFIG="{\"device\": \"team0\", \"runner\": {\"name\": \"lacp\", \"fast_rate\": true, \"tx_hash\": [\"eth\", \"ipv4\", \"ipv6\"]}, \"link_watch\": {\"name\": \"ethtool\"}, \"ports\": {\"ens1f1\": {}, \"ens2f0\": {}}}"
```

- I have tried with and without STP on the `br0` interface, in case of conflict but no change.
- With `"debug_level: 2"` in team configuration, and with network manager in debug level, I have those logs, but it seems there is nothing relevant in them:

```
Sep 11 16:26:39 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834399.5499] ifcfg-rh: add connection /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-team0.1826 (c5726afe-2458-492c-9089-f6828559ab9b,"team0.1826")
Sep 11 16:26:39 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834399.5504] manager: (team0.1826): new VLAN device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/33)
Sep 11 16:26:39 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834399.5520] audit: op="connection-add" uuid="c5726afe-2458-492c-9089-f6828559ab9b" name="team0.1826" pid=1374856 uid=0 result="success"
Sep 11 16:26:39 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834399.5585] device (team0.1826): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Sep 11 16:26:39 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834399.5728] device (team0.1826): carrier: link connected
Sep 11 16:26:39 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834399.5744] device (team0.1826): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 11 16:26:39 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834399.5799] policy: auto-activating connection 'team0.1826' (c5726afe-2458-492c-9089-f6828559ab9b)
Sep 11 16:26:39 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834399.5805] device (team0.1826): Activation: starting connection 'team0.1826' (c5726afe-2458-492c-9089-f6828559ab9b)
Sep 11 16:26:39 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834399.5806] device (team0.1826): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 11 16:26:39 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834399.5811] device (team0.1826): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 11 16:26:39 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834399.5836] device (team0.1826): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 11 16:26:39 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834399.5923] device (br0): attached bridge port team0.1826
Sep 11 16:26:39 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834399.5923] device (team0.1826): Activation: connection 'team0.1826' enslaved, continuing activation
Sep 11 16:26:39 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834399.5925] device (br0): IPv4 config waiting until carrier is on
Sep 11 16:26:39 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834399.5925] device (br0): IPv6 config waiting until carrier is on
Sep 11 16:26:39 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834399.5926] device (team0.1826): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 11 16:26:39 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834399.5933] device (team0.1826): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 11 16:26:39 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834399.5935] device (team0.1826): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 11 16:26:39 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834399.5947] device (team0.1826): Activation: successful, device activated.
Sep 11 16:26:41 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: ens1f1: Changed port state: "current" -> "disabled"
Sep 11 16:26:41 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: ens1f1: ethtool-link went down.
Sep 11 16:26:41 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: ens2f0: Changed port state: "current" -> "disabled"
Sep 11 16:26:41 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: carrier changed to DOWN
Sep 11 16:26:41 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: ens2f0: ethtool-link went down.
Sep 11 16:26:47 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834407.5362] device (team0.1655): state change: activated -> unavailable (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 11 16:26:47 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834407.5503] device (team0.1659): state change: activated -> unavailable (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 11 16:26:47 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834407.5655] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Sep 11 16:26:47 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834407.5668] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Sep 11 16:26:47 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834407.5669] policy: set 'team0.1661' (team0.1661) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Sep 11 16:26:47 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834407.5676] device (team0.1661): state change: activated -> unavailable (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 11 16:26:47 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834407.5825] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Sep 11 16:28:26 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834506.7929] agent-manager: req[0x55ac4d810020, :1.6180426/nmcli-connect/0]: agent registered
Sep 11 16:28:26 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834506.7941] device (br0): state change: ip-config -> deactivating (reason 'new-activation', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 11 16:28:26 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834506.7944] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Sep 11 16:28:26 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834506.7947] device (br0): disconnecting for new activation request.
Sep 11 16:28:26 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834506.7947] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="42451cd5-641a-45cf-8c4f-be4dc4227136" name="br0" pid=1377109 uid=0 result="success"
Sep 11 16:28:26 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834506.7947] device (br0): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'new-activation', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 11 16:28:26 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834506.8127] device (br0): detached bridge port team0.1826
Sep 11 16:28:26 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834506.8143] device (br0): Activation: starting connection 'br0' (42451cd5-641a-45cf-8c4f-be4dc4227136)
Sep 11 16:28:26 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834506.8149] device (team0.1826): state change: activated -> disconnected (reason 'new-activation', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 11 16:28:26 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834506.8202] device (br0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 11 16:28:26 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834506.8205] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Sep 11 16:28:26 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834506.8373] device (team0.1826): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'user-requested', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 11 16:28:26 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834506.8377] policy: auto-activating connection 'team0.1826' (c5726afe-2458-492c-9089-f6828559ab9b)
Sep 11 16:28:26 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834506.8379] device (br0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 11 16:28:26 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834506.8401] device (team0.1826): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'user-requested', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Sep 11 16:28:26 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834506.8408] device (team0.1826): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'user-requested', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Sep 11 16:28:26 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834506.8414] device (team0.1826): Activation: starting connection 'team0.1826' (c5726afe-2458-492c-9089-f6828559ab9b)
Sep 11 16:28:26 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834506.8414] device (team0.1826): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 11 16:28:26 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834506.8419] device (br0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 11 16:28:26 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834506.8421] device (br0): IPv4 config waiting until carrier is on
Sep 11 16:28:26 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834506.8421] device (br0): IPv6 config waiting until carrier is on
Sep 11 16:28:26 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834506.8423] device (team0.1826): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 11 16:28:26 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834506.8568] device (team0.1826): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 11 16:28:26 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834506.8793] device (br0): attached bridge port team0.1826
Sep 11 16:28:26 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834506.8793] device (team0.1826): Activation: connection 'team0.1826' enslaved, continuing activation
Sep 11 16:28:26 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834506.8794] device (br0): IPv4 config waiting until carrier is on
Sep 11 16:28:26 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834506.8795] device (br0): IPv6 config waiting until carrier is on
Sep 11 16:28:26 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834506.8796] device (team0.1826): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 11 16:28:26 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834506.8802] device (team0.1826): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 11 16:28:26 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834506.8803] device (team0.1826): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 11 16:28:26 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834506.8814] device (team0.1826): Activation: successful, device activated.
Sep 11 16:29:21 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834561.1835] device (team0.1826): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'connection-removed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 11 16:29:21 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834561.1987] device (br0): detached bridge port team0.1826
Sep 11 16:29:21 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834561.1987] device (team0.1826): released from master device br0
Sep 11 16:29:21 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834561.1999] audit: op="connection-delete" uuid="c5726afe-2458-492c-9089-f6828559ab9b" name="team0.1826" pid=1378747 uid=0 result="success"
Sep 11 16:29:21 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834561.2000] device (team0.1826): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'connection-removed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 11 16:29:21 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834561.2243] device (team0.1826): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'user-requested', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 11 16:31:41 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: ens1f1: Changed port state: "disabled" -> "expired"
Sep 11 16:31:41 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: ens1f1: ethtool-link went up.
Sep 11 16:31:41 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834701.6413] device (ens1f1): carrier: link connected
Sep 11 16:31:41 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: ens2f0: Changed port state: "disabled" -> "expired"
Sep 11 16:31:41 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: ens2f0: ethtool-link went up.
Sep 11 16:31:41 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834701.9899] device (ens2f0): carrier: link connected
Sep 11 16:31:42 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: ens1f1: Changed port state: "expired" -> "current"
Sep 11 16:31:42 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: carrier changed to UP
Sep 11 16:31:42 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834702.6431] device (team0): carrier: link connected
Sep 11 16:31:42 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834702.6434] device (team0.1655): carrier: link connected
Sep 11 16:31:42 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834702.6436] device (team0.1659): carrier: link connected
Sep 11 16:31:42 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834702.6438] device (team0.1661): carrier: link connected
Sep 11 16:31:42 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834702.6439] device (team0.1655): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 11 16:31:42 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834702.6502] device (team0.1659): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 11 16:31:42 hostname NetworkManager[1059]: <info>  [1599834702.6564] device (team0.1661): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
```

Is anyone having an idea on how this happens, and how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

It happens that I managed to mount the bridge, by following exactly those steps:

- Marking every connection as down

```
nmcli con down team0.1826
nmcli con down team0.1651
nmcli con down team0.1655
nmcli con down team0
nmcli con down ens1f1
nmcli con down ens2f0
```

Point was: no interface up before starting.

- recreating the vlan connection without the ips

```
nmcli con del team0.1826
nmcli con add type vlan con-name team0.1826 ifname team0.1826 dev team0 id 1826
```

- creating the bridge. I disabled STP but I don't think it has any incidence, just seen this a lot on KVM tutorials.

```
nmcli connection add type bridge con-name br0 ifname br0 bridge.stp no
```

- tying the bridge and the vlan together

```
nmcli con mod team0.1826 connection.master br0 connection.slave-type bridge
```

- configuring the bridge

```
nmcli con mod br0 ipv4.method manual ipv4.addresses '172.18.x.y/28' ipv4.gateway '172.18.x.z'
```

- starting everything

```
nmcli con up br0
nmcli con up team0.1826
nmcli con up team0
nmcli con up ens1f1
nmcli con up ens2f0
nmcli con up team0.1651
nmcli con up team0.1655
```

And voilà! the bridge did go up.

I think that NetworkManager may be a little picky. I strongly suspect that splitting  `team0.1826` interface into creation and tying to bridge steps did the trick.